# Open files in PHPStorm with Vagrant+Symfony application

Tags: symfony, phpstorm

I know you can open files from Symfony profiler or exception file links using this in `project/app/config.yml` :

```
framework:
    ide: "phpstorm://open?file=%%f&line=%%l"
```

More info: http://developer.happyr.com/open-files-in-phpstorm-from-you-symfony-application

However as I'm using vagrant, the file path of the server doesn't match my host.

I have created a PHP web application server in PHPStorm with the propper path mappings, but still doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: "Doesn't work" how?

Comment: Cannot find file: '/var/www/vagrant/..." it's like it's trying to open the file with the path inside the vagrant.

Comment: related issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-65879

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When running your app in a container or in a virtual machine, you can tell Symfony to map files from the guest to the host by changing their prefix. This map should be specified at the end of the URL template, using & and > as guest-to-host separators:

```
// /path/to/guest/.../file will be opened
// as /path/to/host/.../file on the host
// as /path/to/host/.../file on the host
'phpstorm://%f:%l&/path/to/guest/>/path/to/host/&/foo/>/bar/&...'
```

[Symfony FrameworkBundle Configuration - IDE](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#ide)

Comment: Thanks that's new in 3.2 !

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by Jeffry no longer works unfortunately :(. When In configure that with my paths the profiler throws:

```
ParameterNotFoundException
You have requested a non-existent parameter "f:".
```

I have configured the path according to this line in the SF docs: `This map should be specified at the end of the URL template`, which results in this:

```
phpstorm://open?url=file://%%f&line=%%l&/path/to/guest/>/path/to/host/
```

However, it does open PHPStorm, but phpstorm does not open the file, so i'm a bit stuck here now.

Answer (score 0):

This solves the issue with the file not opening in PhpStorm from a Vagrant:

`phpstorm://open?file=%%f&line=%%l&/path/to/guest/>/path/to/host/`

Source: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-65879